# How can I recognize when the user is editing or inserting something?

Tags: forms

I have a form which adds some information. I used `hook_form()` for inserting and loading data. units/add calls the form to insert data and units/%unitid/edit calls the form to edit data. In `hook_form_submit()`, how can I recognize when the user is editing or inserting something? Should I use `$delta`, or is it no longer available in Drupal 7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Field `nid` is unset if node is created. Optionally, you can check if `arg(1) === 'add'`